# relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32 against `.data'

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors

I am having this error compiling this code:

```
section .text
   global _WinMain     ;must be declared for linker (ld)
    
_WinMain@16:                ;tells linker entry point
   mov  edx,len     ;message length
   mov  ecx,msg     ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel
    
   mov  eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;string to be printed
len equ $ - msg     ;length of the string
```

i cave a win64 and i compile with

```
all:
    nasm -o asm.o -f win64 main.asm
    ld asm.o -o asm.exe
```

I have an Intel core i5 running windows 11
i am following a tutorial and it runs fine on the site.

Comment: That's from a 32-bit Linux tutorial.  You changed the entry point from `_start`, and the build commands from `nasm -felf32` to `nasm -fwin64`. (Or else the person that post the tutorial changed crap without checking, and is polluting the web with garbage.) Even if it did link, it wouldn't run correctly.  Find a tutorial for Windows x64.

Comment: Assembly is different for each architecture and each operating system.  You have a different operating system than the tutorial, so it won't work.  You are also trying to assemble for a different architecture which doubly won't work.